# display 10 records in table using repeat

Tags: apex, visualforce, repeat

I am getting an error in the below code..Its a very simple one actually but i am missing someething
I am just trying to show 10 record in a table using apex:repeat

VF page

```
<apex:page controller="queryaccountrecords" >

<apex:form >
<apex:pageBlockTable>
<apex:pageBlock title="Account Records">
<apex:outputPanel id="ContactDetail" >
<apex:repeat value="{!accts }" var="dbItem">
<apex:outputText value="{!dbItem.Name}" /><br/>
</apex:repeat>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:pageBlock>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

controller:

```
public class queryaccountrecords {



    public queryaccountrecords()
     {
     Account[] accts = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 10];

    }


}
```

Comment: and what else i need to do if i want to show this data in a pdf on click of a button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is updated code :

```
public class MyController {
public List<Account> accts{get;set;}
    public MyController (){ 
        accts = [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 10];
    }
  public PageReference deliverAsPDF() {
     PageReference pdf =  Page.generatePdf;
            pdf.getParameters().put('p','p');
               pdf.setRedirect(true);
                       return pdf;
  }
  public String chooseRender {
     get { 
           return (ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('p') != null) ? 'pdf' : null; 
         }
  }
}
```

And vf page is :

```
<apex:page controller="MyController" renderAs="{!if($CurrentPage.parameters.p == null, null, 'pdf')}"> 
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Account Records">
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!accts}" var="acc">
                <apex:column value="{!acc.Name}"/> 
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <apex:outputLink rendered="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.p == null}" value="/apex/generatePdf?p=true" target="_blank">GENERATE PDF</apex:outputLink>
</apex:page>
```

Thanks

Aryan

Comment: and what else i need to do if i want to show this data in a pdf on click of a button?

Comment: u can use  **renderAs="pdf"**    attribute in   **<apex:page>**  and apply some css for pdf design.

Comment: but i want to show pdf on click of a button..if i add render as = pdf..the same page will be shown as a pdf

Comment: Means you have a Requirement to Download the Visualforce Page as PDF When click on CommandButton ??

Comment: Yes....@aryan kapoor

Comment: You need to have visual force page and render it as pdf page.

see here:
[http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Creating_Professional_PDF_Documents_with_CSS_and_Visualforce]

Comment: so i need to create a new Vf page on click of a button and that Vf page will also be same as firsdt VF page but it will contain "render as pdf" attribute..am i right?

Comment: Plz check my updated code ... I think you are asking for this only ...

Comment: Thanks..and if i have a requirement that in every record there is a check box and whichever checkbox i have clicked..only that record should appear in pdf..then is ithat possible too??

Comment: yup that is possible...and for that u need to put some effort..

Answer (score 1):

Your `accts` variable should be visible to VF page. Try below code

```
public class queryaccountrecords {
    public Account[] accts{get;set;}
    public queryaccountrecords()
     {
        accts= [SELECT Name FROM Account LIMIT 10];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur help..I tried ur code..I am getting an error - Error: Unknown property 'queryaccountrecords.accts
@highfive

Comment: edited.use `public` access modifier